# PHP no me muestra los errores en formulario

Tags: php, html

Buenas a todos, estoy creando un formulario en HTML y PHP, y la hora de enviarlo quiero que me muestre un mensaje de error si alguno de los campos no cumple el requisito. Mi problema es que solo se queda en el primer campo nombre si doy a Enviar si llenar nada debería mostrarme errores en todos los campos, y si he llenado algún campo y aun así da error, esos campos deberían estar llenos con el valor introducido, hasta ahí mis pruebas han ido bien, y ¿cuál es mi problema?

- No me valida fechaNacimiento ni clave
- El nombre siempre se me queda pintado en el formulario
- Si escribo en todos los campos, nombre, clave y fechaNacimiento se me quedan pintados en el formulario.

Mi código PHP:

```
<head>
    <?php
        error_reporting (0);
        $partesFecha=explode("/",$_POST['fechaNacimiento']);
        $diaActual=$partesFecha[0];
        $mesActual=$partesFecha[1];
        $anyoActual=$partesFecha[2];

        if(isset($_POST['Enviar'])){
            $errores = array();
            if (!isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
                $errores[1] = '<span class="error">Introduce un nombre</span>';
            }
            if ((strlen($_POST['clave'] < 6)) && (strlen($_POST['clave']) > 12)) {
                $errores[2] = '<span class="error">La clave debe ser mayor de 6 y menor de 12 caracteres</span>';
            }
            if (!isset($_POST['genero'])) {
                $errores[3] = '<span class="error">Debes elegir un género</span>';
            }
            if ((!checkdate($mesActual, $diaActual, $anyoActual)) && (comprobarMayoriaEdad($diaActual, $mesActual, $anyoActual) < 18)) {
                $errores[4] = '<span class="error">La fecha debe ser dd/mm/yyyy y debes ser mayor de edad</span>';
            }
            if (!isset($_POST['pais'])) {
                $errores[5] = '<span class="error">Debes elegir un pais</span>';
            }
            if (!isset($_POST['acept'])) {
                $errores[6] = '<span class="error">Debes aceptar las condiciones</span>';
            } else {
                $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                $clave = $_POST['clave'];
                $genero = $_POST['genero'];
                $pais = $_POST['pais'];
                $acepto = $_POST['acept'];
            }
        }

        function comprobarMayoriaEdad($dia, $mes, $anyo){
            /*Fecha actual*/
            $diaAct=date("d");
            $mesAct=date("m");
            $anyoAct=date("Y");
            /*Fecha nacimiento*/
            $diaNac=$dia;
            $mesNac=$mes;
            $anyoNac=$anyo;
            /*Si el mes es el mismo pero el dia actual es inferior al que cumple años, no ha cumplido años, y restamos un año*/
            if(($mesNac==$mesAct)&&($diaNac>$diaAct)){
                $anyoAct=($anyoAct-1);
            }
            /*Si el mes actual es menor que el de nacimiento, no ha cumplido años y restamos un año*/
            if($mesNac>$mesAct){
                $anyoAct=($anyoAct-1);
            }
            /*Restamos los años para obtener la edad*/
            $edad=($anyoAct-$anyoNac);

            return $edad;
        }
    ?>
</head>
```

Mi formulario en HTML:

```
<form name="Formulario" method="post" action=''>
    Nombre:
    <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){echo $_POST['nombre'];}?>" />
    <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[1];}?>
    <br/>
    <br/> Contraseña:
    <input type="password" name="clave" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['clave'])){echo $_POST['clave'];}?>" />
    <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[2];}?>
    <br>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="genero" value="H" />H
    <input type="radio" name="genero" value="M" />M
    <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[3];}?>
    <br/>
    <br/> Fecha de nacimiento:
    <input type="text" name="fechaNacimiento" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fechaNacimiento'])){echo $_POST['fechaNacimiento'];}?>" />
    <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[4];}?>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <select name="pais[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="España">España</option>
        <option value="Francia">Francia</option>
        <option value="Italia">Italia</option>
    </select>
    <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[5];}?>
    <br/>
    <br/> Acepto las condiciones:
    <input type="checkbox" name="acept" value="OK" />
    <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[6];}?>
    <br>
    <br/> Comentarios:
    <textarea name="comentarios" rows="10" cols="30" value=""></textarea>
    <br>
    <br/> Foto:
    <input type="file" name="foto" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: a que te refieres con pintado?

Comment: Me refiero a que se muestra, que no se elimina.

Comment: Comprueba las condiciones. Algunas están mal y nunca se entrará en ellas (p.e.: `(strlen($_POST['clave'] < 6)) && (strlen($_POST['clave']) > 12)` nunca se va a dar el caso de que la longitud de la clave sea a la vez menor que 6 y mayor que 12, deberías usar `||` en vez de `&&`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comprueba las condiciones. Algunas contienen errores y nunca se entrará en ellas. Además tienes que tener en cuenta que algunos tipos de campos no se envían nunca, mientras que otros sólo se envían cuando se ha "interactuado" con ellos (por ejemplo radios y checkboxes).

Vamos a ver los campos y validaciones uno a uno:

---

El **nombre** es un tipo texto (`input type='text'`) por lo que siempre se enviará con el formulario (incluso si está vacío), por lo que se considerará que siempre es válido, incluso si se envía vacío. No sólo deberías comprobar que está, sino también que tenga tamaño (realmente te sobraría con esto último):

```
if ($_POST['nombre'] != "") {
```

Luego la **clave** tiene la comprobación mal:

```
if ((strlen($_POST['clave'] < 6)) && (strlen($_POST['clave']) > 12)) {
```

Nunca se va a dar el caso de que la longitud de la clave sea a la vez menor que 6 y mayor que 12, deberías usar `||` en lugar de `&&` porque lo que quieres comprobar es que la longitud de la clave no sea menor que 6 o mayor que 12:

```
if ((strlen($_POST['clave'] < 6)) || (strlen($_POST['clave']) > 12)) {
```

La **fecha de nacimiento** falla porque en la función `comprobarMayoriaEdad` no se comprueba el caso en el que la fecha esté vacía. Que hace que si no se ha pasado ninguna fecha, entonces la edad calculada será igual al año actual (siempre mayor de edad).

Además, tiene el mismo problema que la clave, el `if` debería ser con un `||` o te encontrarás con el problema que o se cumplen las dos o no se mostrará error. Entonces debería ser algo como esto:

```
if ((!checkdate($mesActual, $diaActual, $anyoActual)) || (comprobarMayoriaEdad($diaActual, $mesActual, $anyoActual) < 18)) {
```

Y en la función `comprobarMayoriaEdad` podrías añadir una primera línea que devuelva 0 si el año (`$anyo`) no está especificado:

```
function comprobarMayoriaEdad($dia, $mes, $anyo){
    if (!$anyo) return 0;
    ....
```

---

Ahora, sobre los campos que se quedan pintados. Eso ocurre porque los estás escribiendo en el PHP:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){echo $_POST['nombre'];}?>" />
...
<input type="password" name="clave" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['clave'])){echo $_POST['clave'];}?>" />
...
<input type="text" name="fechaNacimiento" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fechaNacimiento'])){echo $_POST['fechaNacimiento'];}?>" />
...
```

Lo que podrías hacer es añadir una variable cuando se hayan realizado todas las comprobaciones y sean correctas y sólo mostrar los valores si algo fue mal.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que la validacion del los campos de tu formulario es mas sencilla si la haces con Jquery. Yo suelo utilizar este plugin
 https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Otra posible solucion es agregar la propiedad required a los elementos del DOM

```
<input type="radio" name="genero" value="H" required="true" />
```

Y para el password seria algo asi

```
<input type="radio" name="genero" value="H" required="true" maxlength="12"/>
```

maxlenght, no te va a mostrar un mensaje, es el numero maximo de caracteres que el usuario puede ingresar

Comment: Es un ejercicio para clase y debo usar solamente PHP.

Comment: Usar validación sólo en el lado del cliente es mala práctica. La validación con JavaScript o HTML puede saltarse fácilmente y enviar valores incorrectos al servidor.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php
    error_reporting (0);
    $partesFecha=explode("/",$_POST['fechaNacimiento']);
    $diaActual=$partesFecha[0];
    $mesActual=$partesFecha[1];
    $anyoActual=$partesFecha[2];

    if(isset($_POST['Enviar'])){
        $errores = array();
        if ( $_POST['nombre'] == '' ) {
            $errores[1] = '<span class="error">Introduce un nombre</span>';
        }
        if ( strlen($_POST['clave']) < 6 or strlen($_POST['clave']) > 12 ) {
            $errores[2] = '<span class="error">La clave debe ser mayor de 6 y menor de 12 caracteres</span>';
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['genero'])) {
            $errores[3] = '<span class="error">Debes elegir un género</span>';
        }
        if (!checkdate($mesActual, $diaActual, $anyoActual) && comprobarMayoriaEdad($diaActual, $mesActual, $anyoActual) < 18) {
            $errores[4] = '<span class="error">La fecha debe ser dd/mm/yyyy y debes ser mayor de edad</span>';
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['pais'])) {
            $errores[5] = '<span class="error">Debes elegir un pais</span>';
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['acept'])) {
            $errores[6] = '<span class="error">Debes aceptar las condiciones</span>';
        } else {
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $clave = $_POST['clave'];
            $genero = $_POST['genero'];
            $pais = $_POST['pais'];
            $acepto = $_POST['acept'];
        }
    }

    function comprobarMayoriaEdad($dia, $mes, $anyo){
        /*Fecha actual*/
        $diaAct=date("d");
        $mesAct=date("m");
        $anyoAct=date("Y");
        /*Fecha nacimiento*/
        $diaNac=$dia;
        $mesNac=$mes;
        $anyoNac=$anyo;
        /*Si el mes es el mismo pero el dia actual es inferior al que cumple años, no ha cumplido años, y restamos un año*/
        if(($mesNac==$mesAct)&&($diaNac>$diaAct)){
            $anyoAct=($anyoAct-1);
        }
        /*Si el mes actual es menor que el de nacimiento, no ha cumplido años y restamos un año*/
        if($mesNac>$mesAct){
            $anyoAct=($anyoAct-1);
        }
        /*Restamos los años para obtener la edad*/
        $edad=($anyoAct-$anyoNac);

        return $edad;
    }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="Formulario" method="post" action='' autocomplete="off" >
        Nombre:
        <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){echo $_POST['nombre'];}?>" />
        <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[1];}?>
        <br/>
        <br/> Contraseña:
        <input type="password" name="clave" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['clave'])){echo $_POST['clave'];}?>" />
        <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[2];}?>
        <br>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="genero" value="H" />H
        <input type="radio" name="genero" value="M" />M
        <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[3];}?>
        <br/>
        <br/> Fecha de nacimiento:
        <input type="text" name="fechaNacimiento" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fechaNacimiento'])){echo $_POST['fechaNacimiento'];}?>" />
        <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[4];}?>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <select name="pais[]" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="España">España</option>
            <option value="Francia">Francia</option>
            <option value="Italia">Italia</option>
        </select>
        <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[5];}?>
        <br/>
        <br/> Acepto las condiciones:
        <input type="checkbox" name="acept" value="OK" />
        <?php if(isset($errores)){echo $errores[6]; var_dump($errores); }?>
        <br>
        <br/> Comentarios:
        <textarea name="comentarios" rows="10" cols="30" value=""></textarea>
        <br>
        <br/> Foto:
        <input type="file" name="foto" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Fija te de algunas cosas
primero hay mas paréntesis de los adecuado en las sentencias de los IF
segundo pusiste `if(!isset($_POST['nombre']))` esto siente sera falso porque si envías el formulario ya existe lo que tenias que validar es que este vacío o no

**Recomendación:**
Lo que quieras que deje error por vacio o no usa aparte de eso  la etiqueta required de html5
para la fecha usa el tipo date
y como no puedes ser de varios parisea quitale a los paises el hecho de que sea un array.

Comment: La cosa es que si puedes elegir varios paises.

Answer (score 0):

1.1) En clave debes cambiar el `&&` por `||` ya que estas diciendo que si la clave es MENOR A 6 Y MAYOR A 12 debe cumplir esas 2 condiciones...

1.2) Tambien debes cambiar la operacion `&&` por `||` porque estas validando ademas el formato, si cumple el formato dd/mm/yyyy Y no es menor de edad entonces entraria a mostrar el error, sin embargo si es mayor de edad PERO el formato esta mal no validaria no mostraria el error. En esta opcion yo separaria las validaciones seria el orden

```
if ((!checkdate($mesActual, $diaActual, $anyoActual)){
     echo "error en fecha formato"
}else if (comprobarMayoriaEdad($diaActual, $mesActual, $anyoActual) < 18){
     echo "menor de edad";
}
```

Y como segundo error, se quedan "pintados" porque no los actualizas, lo que yo haria seria setear variables desde la validación al HTML directamente

```
if($clave < 6 || $clave > 12){
    $error_clave = true;
}
```

HTML

```
 <input type="password" name="clave" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['clave'])){echo $_POST['clave'];}?>" />
 <?php if($error_clave){
      echo '<span class="error">Error en la clave</span>'
   }
 ?>
```